# RelayCommand trigger CanExecute MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, icommand

Little confused with my RelayCommands:

I have a button in my Usercontrol resources bound to SelectedProduct:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding ModelName, BindingGroupName=Group1,
         UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, 
         NotifyOnValidationError=True}"/>
<Button Content="Save" Command="{Binding DataContext.SaveProductCommand, 
        RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}" />
```

which triggers the following:

```
    public RelayCommand<object> SaveProductCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_saveproductcommand == null)
                _saveproductcommand = new RelayCommand<object>(SaveProductEdits, CanSaveProduct);
            return _saveproductcommand;
        }
    }

    private bool CanSaveProduct(Object param)
    {
        if (_ESTContext.Products.Find(SelectedProduct.ModelName) != null)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }        
    private void SaveProductEdits(object param)
    {
        UpdateProductBindingGroup.CommitEdit();
        var mod = SelectedProduct as Product;
        if (SelectedProductIndex == -1)
            _products.Add(mod);
        else
        {
            var oldmod = _products.Select(e => e).Where(e => e.ModelID == mod.ModelID).First();
            if (oldmod != null)
                oldmod = mod;
        }
        SelectedProduct = null;
    }
```

When the user edits the textbox and clicks the "Save" button, I want it to evaluate the "CanSaveProduct" at that time.  It seems to me that it's being evaluated when the ViewModel is created. I've also tried using SaveProductCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged(), but maybe I'm placing it in the wrong place...

I'm looking for some guidance as to what i'm doing wrong, and how I can execute my desired behaviour

Comment: From your code, I would guess you need to be calling `SaveProductCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged()` whenever `SelectedProduct.ModelName` changes.

Comment: Ran out for lunch so ill try it in a bit. I recall trying that in the setter of SelectedProduct, but it still does not evaluate the canExecute.

Comment: Is there any reason you are using `UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit`? I've always just used `PropertyChanged`, along with `Mode=TwoWay` so that the source property is updated whenever the text in the textbox is changed, and since the target property changed, anything that relied on that property (like CanExecute for RelayCommand) would update. Since the button is bound to the SaveProductCommand, if it can't execute, the button would be grayed out.

Comment: Im using that because this control is to allow the user to update my object SelectedProduct.  When they click save, selected product then updates with changes. (Also have a cancel button to discard changes)